# SQL and JSON database - R

Tags: r, data, sql, json

I have a database (PostgresSQL) which looks like this:

```
""results"": 
    {""WEBS"": 
        {""WEBS_4"": [{""ip"": ""XXXXX"", ""value"": ""YYYY""}]}}
```

I would like to access the information of `ip`.

Then I write the following query in R, but it does not give me any info:

```
dbGetQuery(conexion,"SELECT 
              data->'results'->'WEBS'->'WEBS_4' ->'ip' as test
                          FROM results;")
```

And when I write this query:

```
dbGetQuery(conexion,"SELECT                   data->'results'->'WEBS'->'WEBS_4' as test
                          FROM results;")
```

I get a result like this `[{""ip"": ""XXXXX"", ""value"": ""YYYY""}]`, that is not very useful in R.

Some other parts of my database are highly nested, so I would like to access those parts which are with the `[]` signs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WEBS_4` is an array with two elements, so there's no `ip` element in it, which explains why this fails:

```
dbGetQuery(conexion,"SELECT 
              data->'results'->'WEBS'->'WEBS_4' ->'ip' as test
                          FROM results;")
```

You need to get the zeroth element of `WEBS_4`, and then you can get the `ip` element of that. This works in a simple PostgreSQL test I set up using `psql`:

```
SELECT  data->'results'->'WEBS'->'WEBS_4'->0->'ip' as test
                          FROM results;
  test   
---------
 "XXXXX"
(1 row)
```

So I suspect the relevant R syntax will be (untested):

```
dbGetQuery(conexion,"SELECT 
              data->'results'->'WEBS'->'WEBS_4'->0->'ip' as test
                          FROM results;")
```